# Telerik MVC grid sort order preserve

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have an old Telerik MVC grid(not Kendo). It's sortable:

```
 .Pageable(pager => pager.Enabled(true).PageSize(20))
               .Selectable()
               .Sortable()
```

The problem is it doesn't preserve its state after navigation or page refresh. My goal is to preserve the sort state in one session. So if the user made a sort on one of the cells he should see that sorting even if he navigates elsewhere on the page, but after he logs out/ or closes the browser it can reset. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

```
if (window.sortHelper) {
            sessionStorage.sortSettings = JSON.stringify(e.sortedColumns[0]);
        } else {
            if (sessionStorage.sortSettings != 'undefined')
                e.sortedColumns[0] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.sortSettings);
            window.sortHelper = true;
        }
```

I did this so far in the OnBeforeDataBinding event, the logic seems to be good, but it doesn't work. Doesn't makes the grid sorted despite that the sortingColumns was set.
Any idea?

Comment: Lots of ways you could do this I guess but if you can capture the 'action' of sorting you could set a cookie for the/each list. this cookie could be read or written server or client side.

Comment: Please refer to following [Link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state).

Comment: @mmushtaq **(not Kendo)**

Comment: Any specific answers? I have no idea where can i capture the sorting event. The OnBeforeDataBindingEvent doesn't works.